# Retrieving dynamic JSONObject value from server response in servlets

Tags: java, javascript, json, servlets

Hi I am getting the access_token value dynamically from server for servlet request it is below: now i want to retrive the access_taken value in to my servlet program.

```
{
    "access_token":"AQWP_EVkqdc7E0wD09J6msmjnUlvilhP304gUIDzl6KKgNxwnHyz_W9nOxS0IroDJwEfVr3n3O-IC9YKc3bjyuwYRm6qbKRiP3A2AzuDjo8ohZERZFRCMyfjjqqDjNJ5J5ReCQDhkFJam51eiqsOeXDg4U_c9XJzc1dUx7Qxck0p9RNE0",
    "expires_in": 5183999
}
```

my code is below:

```
public class Demo extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private static final String PROTECTED_RESOURCE_URL = "http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(first-name,last-name,email-address)";

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public Demo() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
{
    PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
    String authCode = request.getParameter("code");
    request.setAttribute("authCode",authCode);
    out.println(authCode);
    doPost(request,response);
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
{
    PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
    Object url=request.getAttribute("authCode");
    response.sendRedirect("https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken?grant_type=authorization_code&code="+url+"&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/LinkedinMails/dem&client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxx&client_secret=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

}
```

}

Thank You.

Comment: Let us  know if you use any JSON parsing libraries like GSON, Jackson, JSONObject etc

Comment: hi thank you for reply, I am using JSONObject

Comment: Updated my answer for JSONObject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public String doGet(String url) throws Exception {


    URL urlObj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();
    conn.setDoOutput(true);

    String line;
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            conn.getInputStream()));

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        buffer.append(line);
    }

    reader.close();
    conn.disconnect();

    return buffer.toString();
}
```

Now you can call this method from your servlet to get server response in servlet. Hope it will useful to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Gson or Jackson libraries for conveting your JSON response. 
**Using Jackson:**

```
new ObjectMapper().readValue(result, LinkedIn.class);
```

where result is your JSON that contains `access_Token` and `expires`_in

LinkedIn.java

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
public class LinkedIn
{
@JsonProperty("access_token")
private String accessToken;
@JsonProperty("expires_in")
private long expiresIn;

// Getters and setters for expiresOn and accessToken

}
```

In your Servlet/Controller

```
LinkedIn l= new ObjectMapper().readValue(result, LinkedIn.class); // Result is your JSON response which has access token and expires from LinkedIn
l.getAccessToken() ; // Returns you access token
l.getExpiresIn() // Returns you the expires time frame
```

}

**Using JSONObject**

```
 String s="{\n" +
                "    \"access_token\":\"AQWP_EVkqdc7E0wD09J6msmjnUlvilhP304gUIDzl6KKgNxwnHyz_W9nOxS0IroDJwEfVr3n3O-IC9YKc3bjyuwYRm6qbKRiP3A2AzuDjo8ohZERZFRCMyfjjqqDjNJ5J5ReCQDhkFJam51eiqsOeXDg4U_c9XJzc1dUx7Qxck0p9RNE0\",\n" +
                "    \"expires_in\": 5183999\n" +
                "}";  // This contains  your access token JSON

    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject o = (JSONObject) parser.parse(s);
    System.out.println("Access Token:   "+o.get("access_token")); //returns your access token
    System.out.println("Expires: "+o.get("expires_in"));
```

**Getting the Access Token JSON:**

- In your `Demo` Servlet, doPost method, instead of sendRedirect do a
  http Post (Using Apache Http Client or java.net)call to the url.
  Once the HTTP Post is done, You get back a Http response which will be application/json content. So get this String content (which contains application/json). This string content is your access_token sent to you by LinkedIn. Once you get back the response, do this:

  `JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
  JSONObject o = (JSONObject) parser.parse(responseString); // responseString is the JSON that you got from LinkedIn. 
  System.out.println("Access Token:   "+o.get("access_token")); //returns your access token
  System.out.println("Expires: "+o.get("expires_in"));`

Comment: Hi Bhaskara, how to store JSON response in result

Comment: "access_token" and "expires_in" are dynamic values

Comment: Updated my answer. I understand that their "values" are dynamic but the keys "access_token" and "expires_in" remain same. That is one response will have "access_token":"aaa" other response will have "access_token":"bbb"...

Comment: Iam not getting json object from input stream:  i converted to string in this way: InputStream is=request.getInputStream();
      
      String theString = IOUtils.toString(is, "UTF-8");

Comment: I also tried in this way:  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
 {
  
  response.setContentType("application/json");
     PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
     InputStream is=request.getInputStream();
     JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
     try {
         obj.get(is);
     } 
     catch (Exception e) {
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
     System.out.println(obj.toString());

Comment: You may have to do a HTTP Call  using Apache HTTP Client or java.net. Do you use Apache HTTP Client library ?If you do not use Apache  HTTP Client library, follow Vishals answer below. Create a method as defined by Vishal. For that method the parameter should be the URL that you are currenly doing a sendRedirect in Demo servlet. The method return value will be your json with access_token and expires_in. Using this JSON use the code that i have detailed in the updated answer to get your access token

Comment: thank you Bhaskara,it worked by combining both your examples.